# Proving Fundamental Theorem of Algebra using Maximum Principle

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove FTA by using the maximum principle.  Here's what I did,

Let $P$ be a polynomial of degree at least $1$ and assume that $P$ has no zeros.  Define $$f(z):=\frac{1}{P(z)}.$$  Then $f$ is holomorphic on the disk $|z| \leq R$.  Since $f$ is continuous, it attains its maximum value for some complex number, say $w$.  By the Maximum Principle, $w$ lies on the boundary and
$f(z) \leq f(w)$ for all $|z| \leq R$

How do I get a contradiction from here?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

You can't say $f(z) \le f(w)$, because these are complex numbers; what you want is $|f(z)| \le |f(w)|$.

Now use the fact that $|P(z)| \to \infty$ as $|z| \to \infty$.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to put in the absolute value.

Comment: So if |p(z)| goes to infinity then |f(z)| goes to zero.  Which shows that |p(w)| is greater than or equal to zero.

Comment: The point is that $|f(w)|$ goes to $0$ as $R \to \infty$.  What does that say about $f(z)$?

Comment: Sorry but why $|f(w)|$ goes to zero? And what it says about $f(z)$?

Comment: If $w_R$ is a point in the disk $|z|\le R$ that maximizes $|f|$ there, and $R < S$, then $|f(w_R)| \le |f(w_S)|$ (because the maximization over $|z| \le S$ includes $w_R$).  But the Maximum Principle says $|w_R| = R$, and $|f(w_R)| = \max_{|z|=R} |f(z)| \to 0$ as $R \to \infty$.  You can't have a positive, increasing function that goes to $0$.